# Swift Function Error: 'Float' is not convertible to 'Void'

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following function, which generates a quick NSURLConnection request and returns the contents of the page. The function gives me an error on my return line `'Float' is not convertible to 'Void'`

```
func getDJI(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) -> Float {
    let baseURL = "http://geo.crox.net/djia"

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: String(format:"%@/%02d/%02d/%02d",baseURL, year, month, day))!)
    httpGet(request){
        (data, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        } else {
            return (data as NSString).floatValue
        }
    }
}
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.

First, you've got a closure which is supposed to return `Void` and you're trying to return a `Float` from it, and second, you've got a function that is supposed to return a `Float`, but you never return anything from it.

What might make the most sense is for your outer function to return `Void`, and for it to accept a closure that expects a `Float` and returns `Void`:

```
func getDJI(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int, completion:(Float)->Void) -> Void {
    let baseURL = "http://geo.crox.net/djia"

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: String(format:"%@/%02d/%02d/%02d",baseURL, year, month, day))!)
    httpGet(request){
        (data, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        } else {
            completion((data as NSString).floatValue)
        }
    }
}
```

And for the record... `(data as NSString).floatValue` looks pretty suspicious to me...

Answer (score 1):

Your return is inside your `httpGet()` closure, which is supposed to return nothing ("Void").

This looks like you're trying to take an asynchronous `httpGet()` function and treat it as a synchronous function. You can't do that. I don't know what `httpGet()` does, but it's pretty obvious that it returns immediately and calls its closure when data is downloaded.